# swift onDisconnectRemoveValue for user login app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

Im creating a user login. I want to be able to log the user out if the user loses internet connection. I'm `using info/connected` onDisconnectRemoveValue` everything work as expected the only problem is onDisconnectRemoveValue remove the value only when the user get back connection.the value should be remove immediately as soon as it is disconnected.

```
let path = "rquest/frontEnd/users/\(self.currentUserId()!)"
        let isUserLogon = Database.database().reference(withPath: path).child("isUserLogon")
        let lastOnline = Database.database().reference(withPath: path).child("lastOnline")
        let connectedRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            if let isConnected = snapshot.value as? Bool {
                isUserLogon.onDisconnectRemoveValue(completionBlock: { (error, fir) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                })
                isUserLogon.setValue(true, withCompletionBlock: { (error, fir) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: You cannot remove value from firebase database, if you donot have connection to your firebase server.

Comment: `onDisconnectRemoveValue` This happen on server side am I Right on that . The connection should not effect the removal.